# Was Jeremy Corbyn making a comparison?

Tags: comparison, comparative-constructions

As reported by the BBC [here](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-36676018), the Labour leader Jeremy Corbyn is being accused of comparing the state of Israel to Islamic State (IS), he said

> "Our Jewish friends are no more responsible for the actions of Israel or the Netanyahu government than our Muslim friends are for those various self-styled Islamic states or organisations."

Corbin was denounced by the current and previous Senior Rabbis of the UK citing that Corbyn should not be comparing Israel to IS.

When asked about it, Corbin said

> "No, no of course I'm not. The point in the report is that you shouldn't say to somebody just because they're Jewish, you must have an opinion on Israel. Any more than you say to anyone who is a Muslim you must have an opinion on any vile action that's been taken by misquoting the good name of Islam. I just ask people to be respectful and inclusive in their debate."

Was Corbyn actually making a comparison between Israel and IS?

Although his statement is lengthy, the simple pattern Corbyn seems to be using is the comparison

> *A* is to *B* as *C* is to *D*
>   *A* is not more to *B* than *C* is *(not more)* to *D*

it seems to me that what is being compared is the "relationship" of *A* to *B* with the "relationship" of *C* to *D*. It doesn't seem that *A* is being compared to *C*, or that *B* is being compared to *D*.

Am I missing something?

Comment: "A is no more B" is slightly but significantly different from "A is not more to B"  *A is no more Y than Z* is a construction that pretty much only shows up in comparisons, where it could be something like "He is no more **likely to graduate from college** than", and Z could be "I am to become a lion-tamer", implying that both are very unlikely.  It's basically a comparison of the degree of two things, not of the two things themselves.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote - the kind of comparison that's being made here is tied closely to the specific grammar being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you've missed anything as such. From the quotes you mentioned your rather thorough analysis sounds accurate to me.

However, this is the sort of language device that some people will read a lot more meaning into than was intended to be there in the first place, as seen in the rabbis' reaction. This is related to the impression some people will get that being able to use the relationship A->B to describe relationship C->D means that there must be parallels between B and D, however obscure they may be. Israel's actions are already a touchy subject - accidentally implying that their morality may be compared to IS could easily insult those who feel close ties to the nation.

Answer (score 1):

The statement of Corbyn's that attracted much ire yesterday can be described in logical terms as follows:

`P` = "I am Jewish".
`Q` = "I support and/or am responsible for the actions of Netanyahu's and other Israeli premiers".
`R` = "I am Muslim".
`S` = "I support and/or am responsible for the actions of various self-styled Islamic states or organisations". (i.e. Daesh)

We have as Corbyn's statement: `NOT(P implies Q) OR NOT(R implies S)`, or, equivalently, `(P and NOT Q) OR (R and NOT S)` *. The false equivocation is `(Corbyn's statement) implies (Q == S)`.

Courtesy to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=5ef78f63ba22e7dfb2fa44613311b932), there are counterexamples to that. Just type `(NOT(P implies Q) OR NOT(R implies S)) implies (Q XNOR S)` in to the prompt.

Thus the equivocation is a Fallacy / objectively false.

*The case `NOT(P implies Q) AND NOT(R implies S)`, by distribution of the AND gate, is equivalent to `P == R`, or effectively, "The set of Jews is equal to the set of Muslims", which is obviously false.

Comment: Unfortunately, natural languages, and English in particular, don't always follow formal Boolean logic. Politicians are known to use formal and informal fallacies in various subtle ways, so proof that this is not how a computer or mathematician would understand his speech isn't as useful as showing that this is not how a fluent speaker would.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Indeed, _reasoning,_ which is what we express in language, isn't limited to formal logic. Still, I'm glad to see someone attempt this kind of analysis, so I'm not downvoting it even though I disagree with the spirit of it. It sheds light on the topic, or at least it might, except that it contains some errors. Caradhras, would you like to try correcting these errors and making a new analysis? I'd like to see an attempt that isn't easily dismissed by someone who opposes the approach. I'll explain the errors in the next comment.

Comment: (1) Corbyn is not saying "At least one of these is false: (a) All Jews support Netanyahu; (b) All Muslims support ISIS." That's what the `OR` statement means. Corbyn is denying both (a) and (b). (2) The ire is not directed at `Q == S`. That is, Corbyn's critics aren't accusing him of saying that Netanyahu supporters are ISIS supporters, or that the truth values of `Q` and `S` are the same for any 'I'. The critics are saying that Corbyn is implying that Israel is morally comparable to ISIS, that is, evil. (3) Equivocation is not the same as making a deductive error.

Comment: The Boolean-algebra version also omits a subtlety, that Corbyn is comparing levels of responsibility, but it might be OK to ignore that. Anyway, welcome to ELL! :)

Comment: @BenKovitz I thank you for that! 1) Well, originally, I thought changing the `OR` to `AND` and leaving all else intact makes `Q==S` true (which it isn't)  4) I ignored the comparison of levels of responsibility b/c that would seem to delve into mixing natural language with Real Analysis. I know of two Daesh crimes that Bibi has not managed to commit:

`N`:= "Daesh deliberately destroys UNESCO sites en masse"
`M`:= "Israel/Bibi does the same" (false)
`L`:= "Daesh summarily executes prisoners en masse"
`K`:= ditto (last executed person was Adolf Eichmann)
(part 1)

Comment: @BenKovitz Thus formulating the equivocation's 2nd part will need to answer whether it's `(K and L) AND (M and N)` or `(K and L) OR (M and N)`. As the implied standard is 'equally evil', I lean towards the AND. Other war crimes+crimes against humanity can be added but it's all Induction from there.

Or, resorting to logic may be unnecessary, and a head count may suffice, ie the deadliest conflict under Bibi was the Summer 2014 assault on Gaza (UN HRC=2,251 Gazans killed,65% civilians). Compared to <a href="http://en.alalam.ir/news/1742066">10K+ executions</a> by Daesh since Jun 2014...

Comment: @CaradhrasAiguo, the nation of Israel was established by the U.N. and its current goverment was elected in a democratic process, while daesh arrogated authority to themselves by force of arms. Their "executions" should be termed, rather, as "murders." There is no equivalency between military action undertaken by a sovereign nation in retailation for attacks upon its citizens and murders committed by armed criminals. The notion that the issue can be reduced to formal logic, or that a comparison of the numbers of dead establishes that one is "better" or "worse" than the other, is a chimera.

Comment: I wonder if the person who gave this a +1 actually checked whether the Boolean algebra matches the sentence.

Comment: @Caradhras I don't fully understand your thinking about the NMLK version, but it's hard to be clear about tricky things like this in 600-character comments. Even with plenty of space and total clarity, understanding this kind of thing is hard. But here's one thing I'm sure of: The question is about English, so explaining how to get from the English to the Boolean algebra is the main point. The opposing views about Corbyn's sentence differ about what it _means._

Answer (score -1):

This is an interesting question about a convoluted comparison that seems to be open to interpretation. But it's also a much bigger question about a politician's views. I'll give my personal take on things as I try to guess Corbyn's intentions.

In a certain sense, there is an undeniable line drawn between ***Israel or the Netanyahu government*** and ***various self-styled Islamic states or organisations.***

The ***Jewish friends*** are ***no more responsible***, which I infer to mean "not at all responsible." For the sake of clarity, we can attempt to simplify the analogy:

> Jews are not responsible for the actions of Israel or Netanyahu, in the same way that Muslims are not responsible for the actions of ISIS.

I think one can infer a connection between Netanyahu and ISIS if they choose to, but I don't think one **has** to read the connection as explicit. I think the negation of the association (***not responsible for the actions***) allows us to see the connection or not. If you think about it, a negation of association means that there isn't much of a comparison to begin with. It's a clever way to form an analogy, but in Corbyn's case, it has caused too much confusion.

So did Corbyn mean to call out Israel? It's no secret that Corbyn doesn't like Netanyahu politically. Corbyn is a progressive liberal, and Netanyahu is a hardline conservative who loves Donald Trump. Politically, they are opposites. And at least a few members of Corbyn's Labour Party have been accused of being anti-Zionist, while Netanyahu is the world's most outspoken Zionist.

At best, Corbyn was foolish to say something like this, because it has caused a lot of harm to his party. But also consider that a person can be a critic of Netanyahu and of the current governing party of Israel without being against the Israeli people. Indeed, one can be anti-Zionist without being anti-Semitic. Keep in mind, there is such a thing as anti-Zionist Judaism. There are valid ethical arguments both for and against Zionism. Corbyn insists that he is not anti-Semitic and that his party does not tolerate anti-Semitism, and from videos I've watched I actually believe him. (I realize it's dangerous to believe a politician...)

Many Jews get frightened by anti-Zionist rhetoric, and not for bad reason. People who hate Jews are generally anti-Zionist as well. Do Jewish leaders have a motive for accusing Corbyn of being anti-Semitic? Yes, some leaders are probably interested in protecting Israel from a party that might be sympathetic to enemies of the Jewish state -- the Palestinians.

So my answer is as vague as Corbyn's analogy. I don't feel strongly about what I think, but I think this is what happened:

- Corbyn took a shot at Netanyahu by comparing him and his ruling party to ISIS.
- Corbyn isn't racist or anti-Semitic himself, but deep-down he and other party members might sympathize with Palestinians.
- Some British rabbis are worried by Labour Party's anti-Zionist sentiment and have taken this opportunity to denounce Corbyn publicly.

Comment: This reads more as a declaration of your political loyalties than as an explanation to help someone learn English. To keep this on-topic for ELL, could you expand on the grammar and reduce the political side-taking?

Comment: Sorry if I came off strongly like that. I'm trying to answer the question -- giving what I think is a reasonable explanation for why people have reacted the way they did.

Comment: BTW, I haven't downvoted this answer. I think it has the seed of something excellent. I don't think you need to answer from an unbiased or unemotional perspective. Presenting your emotions and loyalties, and showing how they influence (or don't influence) your interpretation, could shed a lot of light on how the construction "A is no more X to B than C is X to D" gets used and understood in English—especially, the way it gets understood by people on different sides of an issue. It seems to me that the construct has a bizarre and disturbing ambiguity. …

Comment: …  Could you briefly explain just enough of the background about Netanyahu, etc., that someone unfamiliar with Israeli politics, British politics, and this form of rhetoric could follow the way you're explaining the two interpretations? If you could get across why you don't see the statement as likening Israel to ISIS, and why other people do, that might be enlightening for people learning English. Then again, I suspect that the same ambiguity occurs in most or even all languages; I don't know. Even so, it might be useful for learners to see: "Ah, they do it, too."

Comment: I agree, I think a better answer would describe the ambiguities of this construct. Will think about it some.

Comment: I'm reading news about Corbyn now, and it seems preposterous to me that people would construe what he said as anti-Semitic. I think I see the issue, which is that he named Netanyahu, who has fervent support from conservative Jewish leaders around the world. I think people are reacting negatively to Corbyn because he doesn't like Netanyahu.

Comment: Only if we assume that Corbyn is a dunce can we believe that he did not intend to imply an equivalence between the nation of Israel and daesh.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Well, there we have it: you hear the opposite side of the ambiguity from what Ringo hears. It would be great if you could _each_ post an answer explaining why you favor your side of the ambiguity.

Comment: @BenKovitz Seems like we need a tiebreaker here...

Comment: @BenKovitz I have no brief for Netanyahu. However, there is nothing ambiguous about Corbyn's statement, as valiantly as he has backed water. The equivalencies are "Jews and Israel" with "Muslims and self-styled Islamic states." This is as plain as day. I defy anyone to diagram this sentence so as to obviate the equivalencies. Corbyn was playing to the base (in two senses of that term.) This is far from unusual in political speech.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Great username, by the way! Suppose I say, "I am not responsible for Ringo's actions, just as I am not responsible for Adolf Hitler's actions." Have I just equated Ringo and Hitler? Actually, I don't want to argue with you about that; I'm hoping you'll feel inspired to write an answer that explains why there is no ambiguity (and addresses the objection I just made). A sentence diagram might be a fantastic way to explain how you understand Corbyn's statement.

Comment: @Ben Kovitz First of all, let's dispense with any consideration of Corbyn's intentions or beliefs, his mooted enmity for Netanyahu or sympathy for the inhabitants of Ramallah, etc. Let's analyze just the words he used. What he is quoted as saying depends for its meaning upon two equivalencies. One is between "Our Jewish friends" and "our Muslim friends;" and the other is between "Israel" and "self-styled Islamic states." Can you or someone else demonstrate that these two equivalencies somehow aren't really there, or that they are **not** the foundation of Corbyn's statement? (continued below)

Comment: (continuation of previous) To me, this is so elementary that it beggars explanation. If the opprobrium was unintended or merely stupid, it is no less onerous for that. To put the issue in clear relief (at least for U.S. citizens who understand the dynamics of "race relations" in our country) imagine the reaction to this statement by a political leader: "Our white friends are no more responsible for the actions of the Ku Klux Klan than our black friends are for the actions of President Obama."

Comment: @P.E.Dant Great example! Post it in an answer! If you could explain how it differs from the example I gave (Ringo<->Hitler), that would be great. And I really like your idea of making a sentence diagram, though if that's inconvenient, I'd say to leave it out. I'd rather see your answer without a diagram than no answer explaining your analysis at all. I agree that you don't need to bother with Corbyn's intentions; the question is simply about what the words mean: how a listener makes sense of them according to the customs of the language.

Comment: The KKK example is a good one. So I've tried other examples in my head (Catholics and the Pope), and some feel more controversial than others. I guess, for me, making a strange analogy between Israel and ISIS is preposterous, and I don't see any connection between the two. And so the statement didn't bother me. But I grant that it could (and maybe should?) bother others.

Comment: @BenKovitz thanks for the great Ringo/Hitler analogy! There's a first in my life, haha.

Comment: @Ringo So you think the comparison _does_ imply an equivalence? You could call Godwin's law. ;) Seriously, I'm still trying to sort this thing out, which is why I haven't tried writing an answer myself. Your remark "for me, making a strange analogy between Israel and ISIS is preposterous, and I don't see any connection between the two" has just induced some enlightenment.

Comment: Godwin? Here? Is nowhere safe?

Comment: @Ringo What I think you haven't realized is that the preposterous analogy between Israel and daesh is precisely the point of Corbyn's statement. I believe that he said exactly what he meant to say: Israel and daesh are entities to be perceived as peers. This message appeals to the "hard" left in the U.K., and Corbyn knows this well. Thus I said above: "Only if we assume that Corbyn is a dunce can we believe that he did not intend to imply an equivalence between the nation of Israel and daesh." His attempts to deny that what he said was what he meant are standard, cynical political connivery.

Comment: @P.E.Dant   I think I'm starting to come around to what you're saying. I initially thought this was something he said off the cuff and regretted afterward. But I just watched the video. It's a rousing speech for his fervent supporters, who started cheering before he even finished the sentence. The anti-Zionism was palpable. Why should the British care about that issue so much, it seemed odd to me. If the Labour Party has anti-Semitism running through it publicly, I would say that's pretty sad. I guess I'm just a naive American!

Comment: @Ringo To fully understand the English (not so much British) emotional reaction to anything bearing on the nation of Israel, an interested reader might start with searches on terms such as "King David Hotel" and "Balfour Declaration." In England especially, "anti-Zionism" has a long history as a "code word" for what is in fact good old fashion (no hyphen there, @BenKovitz) hate, and there is no certain method of determining whether a given use of the term "anti-Zionism" conveys only opposition to the establishment of the Jewish state, or to the existence of Jews.

Comment: I don't think there's anything quite like this "hard left" in the United States. To be honest, I'm kind of shocked by it.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Kinda interesting postscript: I've noticed Trump using the same tactic to court the "alt-right." A few days ago, he suggested that the vandalism of the Jewish cemeteries might have been a setup to make him look bad. Which is the sort of wildly insulting remark that anti-semitic Americans love to hear. Then he pulled it back immediately and acted like he didn't mean to suggest that. To me, it looked like a subtle wink to his racist allies.